# Run React application without server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, tizen, tizen-web-app

Before asking my question I'd like to tell you that I am very new to react and till now I have learned very basic concepts of **react** like component, state, prop, router etc. and may be this question is very funny but I need the solution for that. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

So my question is, can we run react based application without running application on server ?. Basically, I want that, I can directly use index.html file path on web browser and my app starts working.

My understanding is that React js is a javascript library and all the code eventually converted into plain javascript files using babel loader(if we are using ES6). So I think it should be possible to do this.

I have discovered that I can use **webpack** which internally first convert my React based or other js files into normal javascript and make one single bundle file that can be used in Index.html file for further use. I've tried this but only some features are working fine like state, prop but many other features are not working like react-router but when I used npm server all the features start working fine.

Now why I want to do this is because I want to use react js to create **Samsung Tizen TV web application** where I don't think that I can use npm server and all.

If anybody has any solution on that it would be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Please leave the comment before giving down vote

Comment: Did you figure how to do it?

Comment: @ReyanshMishrav No, I didn't try more.

Comment: add this to your `packae.json` `"homepage": "./"`

Answer (score 41):

I added following to package.json before building:

```
"homepage": "./",
```

Quote of reacts terminal output when building:

> The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
>   To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
>   For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
>
> "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

Note: I'm pretty sure this will not work in every project.

Comment: This works great for generating simple apps to run on a file-system using the file:/// protocol string.

Answer (score 16):

The following changes worked for me:

1. Add `"homepage": "."` key-value in `package.json`.
2. Replace [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) with [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter), both imported from [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

(read about difference between `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976069/8334159))

After these changes, do the following to run app without any server:

1. Run `yarn run build` or `npm run build` to create a production build of app.
2. Open `build/index.html` in browser.

Comment: Having done that it finds the main js and css but I get CORS errors when it tries to access files with paths like " 'file:///home...". I've read you can't use these apps directly opening the html in the browser but they need a server

Comment: For those using AJAX calls to a backend web server, you'll be generating requests with no origin (null), since my app was talking to a node web service running locally i just accepted cors address "null" in the allowed origins array.

Comment: Thank you so much this is so simple but I wouldn't have known and it really helped me!!

Answer (score 12):

These few concepts are basically all you need (plus [lifecycles methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)). That's why React rocks, it's very easy to think and reason about, even if you have huge and complicated app.

---

React does work without server, just add script tags and make sure you use JavaScript that current browsers understand **or** download React source and use it anywhere that speaks JS and has DOM.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

For example, Firefox uses React for their new devtools and here's tip that saves you **a lot** of time: it's very easy to use inline styles with React, I can't think of a better tool to design your email templates.

Comment: I think, I am doing something wrong. What I am doing is first I use webpack to create one bundle js file then I used that js file to run on browser

Comment: If you `import` or `require` React, you don't need script tags, it's already there.

Comment: I can send you my dummy project to you If you want to check

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem now, with a default `react`/`react-router` application. And `react-router` also didn't work for me while using [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter). But I found [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2161) where recommended to change `BrowserRouter` to [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter). It fixed my issue. To start the application on emulator (actually, I'm writing for webOS), I changed `src` in `script` tag in `index.html` to my build location.

Answer (score 2):

"homepage":"."
use this to work without web servers. its work for me very well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using standalone babel (jsx) and it runs smoothly https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone

```html
<div id="output"></div>
    <!-- Load Babel -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your custom script here -->
    <script type="text/babel">
      const getMessage = () => "Hello World";
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = getMessage();
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

// This is my code how I run React app on Tizen Studio
index.html in tizen .. run react app and add a ip adress like i did :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body> 

   <script>
       window.open("http://1.1.1.1:4000")
   </script>


</body>
</html>
```

configure xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/HelloWorld" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="fullscreen">
  <tizen:application id="7bo2fXhVaD.HelloWorld" package="7bo2fXhVaD" required_version="2.3"/>
        <access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>

    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>AnalyticsTesting</name>
    <tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/>

    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.display"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/fullscreen"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/volume.set"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo"/>

 <tizen:setting pointing-device-support='disable' />
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="disable" background-support="enable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why this would work and what problem this solves.

Comment: You can run react app in a local environment and then use your local IP to run on SamsungTV with Tizen studio - also you can run in the debugger in Tizen and see how it running on the TV.  With this you can run any react app on the TV and see how it works just with simple local IP :) I hope it helps... I am working heavily on building an app for  SamsungTV and it's really painful and frustrated some times